# Rails count number of row where column matches ID

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, count

So I have a posts model and votes model where the votes are associated to a post by the post_id.

## Posts Model

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :comment_count, :downvote, :id, :text, :title, :upvote, :url, :user_id, :users_voted_up_by, :users_voted_down_by

  serialize :users_voted_up_by
  serialize :users_voted_down_by

  belongs_to :user

  has_many :votes
end
```

## Votes Model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :direction, :post_id, :type, :voter_id

  belongs_to :user

  belongs_to :post

  belongs_to :comment
end
```

I need to query the database for all rows in the `Votes` table that have the current `post_id` of the post in my loop:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <%= Vote.count(:post_id, params[:post_id]) %>
<% end %>
```

**But that just counts every row, what can i write so that they are associated?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The recommended approach would be to use a grouping in the query:

```
<% vote_counts = Vote.group(:post_id).
        where(:post_id => @posts.map(&:id)).count %>
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.id %>: <%= vote_counts[post.id] || 0 %>
<% end %>
```

The advantage to the grouped query is that it only hits the database once.  If you prefer to get a single count for each post for some unfathomable reason you can simply use:

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <%= post.id: %> <%= post.votes.count %>
<% end %>
```

Don't let the simplicity of the second method fool you, though. It's asking for trouble as it involves an N+1 pattern.

Comment: Thank you! For the quick and thorough response!

Comment: Wait, how does post.votes.count work!? I'm not storing the votes in the posts table!

Comment: It works through the `has_many :votes` association that you setup in your `Post` model.  ActiveRecord can figure out to query on votes that are associated with that post based on this.